# upload files to private location in django

Tags: django, file-upload

Everything I found so far in the django documentation on `FileFields` and managing uploaded files seems to assume that you want the uploaded file to end up in a location under `MEDIA_ROOT` that can be served from a `URL` under `MEDIA-URL` there are mechanisms to provide authorization for access to the files but not it seems for them to just not be in the MEDIA_URL path.

What I want to do is to be able to upload files (actually excel spreadsheets) to a location that my application internals can access using `xlrd` to add data to my database via models.

I do not want the files to be downloadable at some URL.

I'd like to be able to use either FileField or some add-on package to upload files to a distinct part of the directory tree - say `UPLOAD_ROOT` which is not under `MEDIA_ROOT` so it can never be served, but is accessible to my `models` and other 'python` code.

Comment: Save the file normally in **MEDIA_ROOT** then with a script read the file save it in another place and remove it.

Comment: Thanks but I really don't want the files to be available even for a short while or in a case where a failure or a bug allows the upload to complete but not the removal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `FileSystemStorage` insists on saving below the `MEDIA_ROOT`, but you can use a different storage for your private files:

```
# in your models.py, or in a separate storage.py
upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_ROOT, base_url='/does/not/matter/')

# models.py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="some/relative/path", storage=upload_storage)
```

Then use the usual Django facilities for file handling... forms, the admin etc. should all work.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try as soon as I can get back to it, and report back.

Comment: @rayjay did you get a change to get back to it?